# js child class toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle, children

How would you toggle the class of an inner div? example:

html:

```
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">1
      <div class="item-more-content">1+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$( function() {

  var $container = $('.masonry').masonry({
    columnWidth: 60
  });

  $container.on( 'click', '.item-content', function() {
    $( this ).parent('.item').toggleClass('is-expanded');
    $( this ).children('.item-more-content').toggleClass('iz-expanded');
    $container.masonry();
  });  

});
```

.parent works, .children does not.

How to toggle css class of child div, "item-more-content"?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (I would comment but don't have enough points yet). Are you sure you want to toggle class 'iz-expanded' and not 'is-expanded' for '.item-more-content'? - typo?